# Python 2.5 list selection simple

Tags: list, python-2.5

How would you go about getting the words "meh" out of this list? Im little confused on the indexing.
I know its simple to most but I am new to programming.

```
x=["spam", "eggs", "ham"]
```

Comment: Did you perhaps mean "seh" instead of "meh"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is zero-indexed, meaning the first word is at index 0, second word at index 1, etc. You can only get words that you have put in. For more info, read up on [Python lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
> x=["spam", "eggs", "ham"] # <-- make list
> x[0] # get each element one at a time
'spam'
> x[1]
'eggs'
> x[2]
'ham'
> x.append("meh") # <-- add "meh"
> x
['spam', 'eggs', 'ham', 'meh']
> x[3] # <-- now we can get "meh" out
'meh'
```

If you want the first letter from each word, to form the word "seh", please see marcog's answer. If you really do want "meh", you can do it like so.

```
# 1st word, 4th letter    ("m") 
#  + 2nd word, 1st letter ("e") 
#  + 3rd word, 1st letter ("h")

print(x[0][3] + x[1][0] + x[2][0])
```

Comment: Oh ok, I see now thank you. I appreciate your time. Im going to try it now.

Comment: @JessRajah if one of the answers helped, please Accept it "click check mark on that answer". It's considered StackOverflow etiquette.

Comment: One more question. Is it possible to make this a whole block of code. Meaning using this in the editor instead of the shell prompt. So when I run it. It will output "meh" in the shell?

Comment: @JessRajah sure, just make the list as above and do `print( x[3] )` to display "meh" to the output terminal

Comment: I'm trying the code. Im using 2.5 by the way. I didn't want to append or add to the list. I wanted to output the word "meh" from just the 3 elements. Im using the editor for this but having trouble.

Comment: @JessRajah see my edit. Can you explain _why_ you are trying to do this? There might be a better way.

Comment: Oh, ok good, this help me out a lot. I can understand now the index selection and concatenation it is right? Anyway yeah its a very vague question I have for some homework. We really don't get taught much its kinda on our own lol.